# Cannot access table names list from a procedure

Tags: plsql, schema

```
declare
type abc IS table of varchar(2000);
def abc:= abc();
tbl_name varchar2(50);
totl_cont number;
scma_name varchar2(10) := 'SCHEMA_NAME';

begin
def.extend(3);
def(1):='table1';
def(2):='table2';

FOR i IN def.FIRST .. def.LAST
  LOOP
      select count(*) into totl_cont from scma_name.def(i);
  END LOOP;

end;
```

In the above code `scma_name.def(i)` is not working. Is is not possible to access table names like this? My objective is to get the row counts from the tables mentioned in the list. I can not make it all tables from the schema, as I want row counts only for the selected tables.

However, this for loop works --

```
FOR i IN def.FIRST .. def.LAST
LOOP
    select def(i) into tbl_name from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tbl_name);
END LOOP;
```

I can't understand why the table names can not be used when used with schema name saved in variable.

Comment: You have several fundamental problems in your code. Please self-study PL/SQL a bit first.

Comment: @user272735, i have rectified the issues,now just the core problem remains, can u help me now

Comment: You need to look into the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` clause.

Comment: object names are stored in the dictionary tables in uppercase by default. Therefore, try converting 'table1' and 'table2' to 'TABLE1' and 'TABLE2' respectively.

Comment: @mmmmmpie thanks...execute immediate worked

Answer (score 0):

final working code:

```
declare
type abc IS table of varchar2(2000);
def abc:= abc();
totl_cont number;
scma_name varchar2(10) := 'schema_name';
totl_name varchar2(100);
sql_stmt varchar2(200);

begin
def.extend(n); -- where n is the number of tables you are using e.g i would be using def.extend(3)

def(1):='table1';
def(2):='table2';
def(3):='table3';
--def(n):='add as many tables you want, given they should be present in the schema :)'

FOR i IN def.FIRST .. def.LAST
  LOOP
      select scma_name||'.'||def(i) into totl_name from dual;
      sql_stmt:= 'select count(*) from '||totl_name;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt into totl_cont;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(def(i) ||' --  ' ||totl_cont);
  END LOOP;

end;
```

You would get your output in the `DBMS_OUTPUT` tab